# TSQL - Pull serial number from string. Possibly regex?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having difficulty finding a reliable way to pull a serial number from a string in SQLServer Management Studio. Such as `iPad2 Black DMPJ491PDVD1 smart case`, or `16BG SF4KNK6BKG5D9`

Looking at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), it seems like the LIKE clause can't handle doing something like looking for 10+ characters in a row that are upper case or numbers, and if something like that is found grab all of those characters.

Can this be done in SQL/T-SQL? I am using SQLServer 2008.

Comment: You can use regex for something like this, provided you can describe a set of rules that distinguish what you're trying to match vs what you're not trying to match. For a start, would it be safe to say that these serial numbers are always made of capital letters and numbers? Do they always start with at least two letters and end with a number? Are they never located as the first group of non-whitespace characters in the input?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an in-line split approach.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'iPad2 Black DMPJ491PDVD1 smart case')
,(2,'16BG SF4KNK6BKG5D9 SF4KNK6BKG5D9')

Select A.* 
      ,SN = B.RetVal
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Distinct RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where Len(RetVal)>=10 
   and patindex('%[0-9]%',RetVal)>0
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeCol                               SN
1   iPad2 Black DMPJ491PDVD1 smart case   DMPJ491PDVD1
2   16BG SF4KNK6BKG5D9                    SF4KNK6BKG5D9
```

Comment: I don't even know how this works yet, but I am going to try to implement this into my existing code. May take a bit, I'll let you know if I have any questions in a day or so.

Comment: @Jeff.Clark Not so complicated when you look at the parts.  The xml portion is splitting the string with a delimiter of a space.  This techiques using §§Split§§ enables us to parse XML characters.  And CROSS APPLY are well worth your time to get comfortable with them.  Let me know if I can help

Comment: Part of this situation is some data entry errors on the database. A few of the serial numbers are entered multiple times in that field, causing extra records. I am now trying to figure out how to limit that.